# How do I display the posts from a custom post type on a category.php page?

Tags: categories, loop

I have set up a `category.php` according to this [wordpress hierarchy diagram](http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png).

When I am on the page http://example.com/category/my-category I want to display all posts that are under `my-category` using the loop:

```
<?php if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()): the_post(); ?>
<h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Wordpress is not showing the posts.
I will also add that this is a custom post type, but that shouldn't matter or should it?

I can use `get_posts()` but then what is the point of having a `category.php`?

How do I show the posts in the current category using `the_loop`?

Comment: "*I will also add that this is a custom post type, but that shouldn't matter.*" - are you sure about that?

Comment: @ChipBennett Editted :)

Comment: @ChipBennett Also changed question title to better match the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I will also add that this is a custom post type, but that shouldn't matter.

In fact, this *is* your problem.

By default, the Category Archive Index will only query posts from the `post` post-type. You need to tell WordPress to do otherwise, by adding your custom post type to the query via `pre_get_posts`:

```
function wpse140419_add_cpt_to_category_archive( $query ) {
    // Only modify the main query
    // on the category archive index page
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        // Add CPT to the query
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'your-cpt-slug' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse140419_add_cpt_to_category_archive' );
```

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly fast answer! Yes, that was the issue.

Comment: No problem! :) If it solved your issue, please *accept* it (by clicking the checkmark).